# Import/Export PostgreSQL db "without" pg_dump or sql file / backup, etc...?

Tags: database, postgresql, import

I need to import a old db into a new postgre server.

Is there a way to migrate an old database to a new server without using pg_dump?

I don't have the sql file, or the old server backup file, neither the user and the password, just the physical files in the "\data" folder, is there any way to do this?

The target server is in the same version of th old server.

Thanks.

Comment: The old server and target server on same OS and version?

Comment: Yes, same os, same server version

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: its a windows 10 server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well as a test you could try:

```
pg_ctl start -D $DATA
```

Where pg_ctl comes from the target version and the `$DATA` is the the /data directory. You have not said how you came to have just a /data directory. If this came from an unclean shutdown or a corrupted drive the possibility exists that the server will not start.

**UPDATE**

To get around `auth` failure find pg_hba.conf and create or modify `local` connection to use `trust` method. For more info see [pg_hba](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-pg-hba-conf.html)  and [trust](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-trust.html). Then you should be able to connect like:

`psql -d some_db -U postgres`

Once in you can use `ALTER ROLE` to change password:

`ALTER ROLE <role_name> WITH PASSWORD 'new_password';`

Comment: Start works, but no connection, auth fail.. I dont have the passwrd for the old server

Comment: Almost done, server starts ok, but my server is in a windows s'o, when i try to use the psql.exe, its say: FATAL role "postgres" does not exist. Even in TRUST mode

Comment: That is not because it is on Windows, it is because the instance you are starting does not have a ```postgres``` role/user.  Do you know what users/roles where in this instance? Maybe take a look in ```pg_hba.conf``` to see if there any user names mentioned?

Comment: I look the file, there is nothing, im totally fckd up :(. Its time to cry... But, thank you a lot man.

Comment: Are you talking about pg_hba.conf file?  It may not be over yet. Go here [postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-postgres.html) and under ```Notes``` look at   ```Single-User Mode```. This gets you in as superuser without specifying a user name.